# Unable to boot Kubuntu

Tags: boot, kubuntu, lightdm

Was running Kubuntu 18.04. Then installed `cinnamon-desktop-environment` and did `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.

On reboot, I'm stuck at a glowing Kubuntu logo!

How do I recover?

Answer (score 1):

From the grub menu, I chose recovery option. This dropped me in to a text based system. I then, set sddm as my display manager and all is well.